# Trying to get my page so there isn't vertical scroll that is the height of the nav bar

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a login page that contains a form that is centered both horizontally and vertically, but you are able to scroll down slightly the height of the navigation bar. I have tried changing the classes and also the height within the style, but it messes with how the form is positioned in the center of the page. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">

    <div class="container">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="login.php">Web App</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="splash.php">Choose Login</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

---

```
<section id="cover" class="min-vh-100">
        <div id="cover-caption">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-white">
                    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto text-center form p-4">
                        <h1 class="display-4 py-2 text-truncate">Student Login.</h1>
                        <div class="px-2">
                            <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="justify-content-center">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="studentnumber">Student Number:</label>
                                    <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" name="studentnumber" placeholder="Student Number">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password:</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

```
<style>
    #cover {
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    #cover-caption {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    /* only used for background overlay not needed for centering */
    form:before {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: -1;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Is this my best option?                                                                                               
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

Comment: I tried those code but can't reproduce that problem... https://jsfiddle.net/zm1bo6sh/

Comment: @sanriot Add the form that I have included beneath the navigation bar to see what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`fixed-top` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement) to solve your problem. Or use flexbox instead of `min-vh-100` class.

```css
   #cover {
     background-size: cover;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     position: relative;
   }

   #cover-caption {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
   }

   /* only used for background overlay not needed for centering */
   form:before {
     content: '';
     height: 100%;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     z-index: -1;
     border-radius: 10px;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top fixed-top">

  <div class="container">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="login.php">Web App</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="splash.php">Choose Login</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</nav>
<section id="cover" class="min-vh-100">
  <div id="cover-caption">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-white">
        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto text-center form p-4">
          <h1 class="display-4 py-2 text-truncate">Student Login.</h1>
          <div class="px-2">
            <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="justify-content-center">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="studentnumber">Student Number:</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" name="studentnumber" placeholder="Student Number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try mine

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- .static-top replaced with .fixed-top -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="login.php">Web App</a>

        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarResponsive"
          aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="splash.php">Choose Login</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section id="cover" class="min-vh-100">
      <div id="cover-caption">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row text-white">
            <div
              class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 mx-auto text-center form p-4"
            >
              <h1 class="display-4 py-2 text-truncate">Student Login.</h1>
              <div class="px-2">
                <form
                  action=""
                  method="POST"
                  autocomplete="off"
                  class="justify-content-center"
                >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="studentnumber"
                      >Student Number:</label
                    >
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      min="1"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="studentnumber"
                      placeholder="Student Number"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    name="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#cover {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#cover-caption {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* only used for background overlay not needed for centering */
form:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Hope it helps ^_^